# Does anyone know of any open source software for drawing/calculating the area of intersection of different shapes?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, math-software, area

I would like to be able to draw any number of different shapes and determine the area of their intersections. I'm looking for free, open source software. I thought about trying to code something up myself, but it would save a lot of time and trouble if there is something out there that can do it already. Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of shapes? Do you mean areas limited by functions, functions and lines?

Comment: I could define them in different ways I suppose. Currently I'm using points to define polygons, but there are some arcs as well. Inkscape looks promising. I'm experimenting with it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have access to MATLAB (I didn't think about mentioning that in the question... oops), and had already searched for a solution utilizing it, but apparently overlooked the one that existed. I searched again and found the function Polygons_intersection on the Matlab Central File Exchange. It is perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Inkscape or directly in PostScript: use one of the shapes as a clipping path and then paint the other shape.

Comment: Inkscape seemed to be the answer until I computed some areas with it and compared them for a sanity check. They failed. Similar shapes produced extremely different values. And I'm hoping for something akin to Inkscape or a CAD package, so I think PostScript is out. Any other ideas?