# Request for apps for Mathematical Drawing

Tags: soft-question, math-software

I have been for long looking for some software apps which can help me draw various mathematical and geometrical figures and drawings.Can someone please tell me something about these which will run on Windows or Android ?

Comment: I like [JSXGraph](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de%2F&ei=dXbHVLqiH8rYggSO7oHwAQ&usg=AFQjCNG_Poj724zl9TAvT36o6r-FVxVDTA&bvm=bv.84349003,d.eXY). (It's a javascript library.)

Comment: Can you give examples of the type of drawing you mean?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1985/23353 http://math.stackexchange.com/q/945843/23353, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/3977/23353, and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/836402/23353

Comment: As it stands, this is *very* broad, and the only real answer is "use LaTeX & friends."  Diagrams that mathematicians draw range from plotting points on a coordinate grid, to graphs (i.e. nodes & edges), commutative diagrams, etc.  There is specialized software for each particular type of drawing, but "mathematical drawing" in general is an immensely broad field.

Answer (score 3):

[**Inkscape**](https://inkscape.org/)

It is a [vector graphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) program that works for Mac/Linux/Windows. It is not strictly mathematical, but is intuitive and produces pictures with high enough quality.

I've used it with success for quite a number of pictures, here are some examples:
[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/455953/26306),
[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/272250/26306),
[3](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/301443/26306),
[4](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/462228/26306),
[5](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/320424/26306),
[6](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/350507/26306),
[7](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/446133/26306),
[8](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/439223/26306).

If you wish, a bit more complex drawings are possible too (the cone below was drawn by hand in 2D).

[image]

I hope it helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I'd like to add that Inkscape works with LaTeX formulas just out of the box. And it can be even more convenient using plugins like textext.

Answer (score 2):

Try these free tools:

- [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/)
- [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/)

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_interactive_geometry_software.